# Closing AutoCAD objects which were obtained via transaction

Tags: c#, .net, autocad

I'm writing an AutoCAD plugin. I'm using transaction to get some objects and I came up with a question - do I need to close (Dispose) objects which I received via transaction?

It is written in the documentation that when Commit() method is called transaction closes every object which had been received via transaction.

> void Commit() -- This function commits the changes made in all the DBObjects opened during the Transaction, and then closes them.

But what is happening when I don't call this method? For example, I'm using transaction only to open an object and receive its layer name. Something like the following:

```
    Database hostapp_workdb = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;
    using ( Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.LockDocument() )
    using ( Transaction transaction = hostapp_workdb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction() )
    {
        Entity entity = transaction.GetObject(objectId, OpenMode.ForRead) as Entity;

        if ( entity != null )
            layer = entity.Layer;
    }
```

As you can see, here I don't call Commit(). What will happen in this case? Will the entity be closed or not (as transaction is in using it must be disposed, so I suppose that it must close all the objects. But I haven't found any confirmation of it in the documentation so it is only my assumption).

Maybe I need to do like this:

```
    ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId();
    string layer = string.Empty;

    Database hostapp_workdb = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;
    using ( Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.LockDocument() )
    using ( Transaction transaction = hostapp_workdb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction() )
    {
        using ( Entity entity = transaction.GetObject(objectId, OpenMode.ForRead) as Entity )
        {
            if ( entity != null )
                layer = entity.Layer;
        }
    }
```

Links to official sources are encouraged.

Thank you.

Comment: Usually you do not need to dispose each entity. In your second case, if 'entity' is 'null', you will get 'Exception' when 'entity.Dispose' is called.

Comment: @SarveshMishra no, I won't. I've run that code and even if entity is null - I won't get any exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember reading a post by Kean Walmsley where he mentioned that if you don't use Commit() a transaction will always use Abort() per default (I will look it up).

Entities will automatically be disposed if they are used in a transaction.
Kean has some nice examples on his blog. You should definitely check them out.
You can find them [here](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2012/08/examples-of-calling-dispose-on-autocad-objects.html)

You also get notifications in your compiler output if entities have to be disposed.

EDIT:

> Forgetting to commit a Transaction
>
> [...] An uncommitted Transaction is Aborted when it is Disposed, so
>   every change you made to the Database in the Transaction is rolled
>   back [...]

It was posted on adndevblog by Stephen Preston [here](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/05/two-common-mistakes-with-transactions.html)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. As I understood I don't need to dispose objects which were opened by transaction because they will be disposed by transaction. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. By disposing your transaction it takes care of your entities inside of it.